# choise option when install syscp on freebsd

Tags: linux, hosting, freebsd

I install syscp on freeport (install from port). Guide me install syscp with choise option (ex: remover ftp or apache on syscp because I intalled ftp server)

Answer (score 0):

There are no options to configure syscp port in its current version, but you can try to edit its Makefile and exclude unnecessary dependencies.
For example, to exclude proftpd, which is dragged by default, go to `/usr/ports/sysutils/syscp`, edit Makefile, find section

```
RUN_DEPENDS+=   \
            dovecot:${PORTSDIR}/mail/dovecot \
            postfix:${PORTSDIR}/mail/postfix \
            proftpd:${PORTSDIR}/ftp/proftpd-mysql \
            webalizer:${PORTSDIR}/www/webalizer
```

and delete or comment corresponding string:

```
RUN_DEPENDS+=   \
            dovecot:${PORTSDIR}/mail/dovecot \
            postfix:${PORTSDIR}/mail/postfix \
          # proftpd:${PORTSDIR}/ftp/proftpd-mysql \
            webalizer:${PORTSDIR}/www/webalizer
```

It should work.